# Import of older MySQL databases (5.6.10) into 5.6.12 generates errors

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I created what I thought was a simple sql dump from the older database before installing the latest version, 5.6.12 on Mac OS X Server. Now I'm trying to import the files but they produce  all produce endless numbers of syntax errors.

Example of errors:

```
[ERROR in query 9] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6' at line 8
[ERROR in query 10] Table 'some.table' doesn't exist
```

Any tips?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An example of an erroring query would be helpful

Comment: show a sample of the actual query from that dump that's causing this error. the error messages aren't enough to figure this out, though obviously your dump has invalid syntax.

Comment: Apparently Stackoverflow thinks too risky to answer my own question so here it is in a comment. The problem was: 

    TYPE=InnoDB 

. As I understand it should be 

    ENGINE=InnoDB

. Sequel Pro on Mac (1.0.2) produces an sql dump with "TYPE" by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question:

> The problem was: TYPE=InnoDB . As I understand it should be ENGINE=InnoDB . Sequel Pro on Mac (1.0.2) produces an sql dump with "TYPE" by default.

Yes, this is deprecated syntax.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html says:

> **Note**
>   The older `TYPE` option was synonymous with `ENGINE`. `TYPE` has been deprecated since MySQL 4.0 but is still supported for backward compatibility in MySQL 5.1 (excepting MySQL 5.1.7). Since MySQL 5.1.8, it produces a warning. It is removed in MySQL 5.5. *You should not use `TYPE` in any new applications, and you should immediately begin conversion of existing applications to use `ENGINE` instead.* (See the Release Notes for MySQL 5.1.8.)

So the keyword has been deprecated since 2006, and removed from the product since 2010!

I found this bug already reported here: https://code.google.com/p/sequel-pro/issues/detail?id=1668

The dev's reply is that Sequel Pro uses SHOW CREATE TABLE to export table definitions.  If your SQL_MODE = "MYSQL323" or "MYSQL40", then SHOW CREATE TABLE will use the outdated TYPE option instead of the proper ENGINE option.  So you can work around the issue by making sure  your SQL_MODE is not configured for compatibility with an old version of MySQL.